# Is this possible for getting external storage path in android kitkat upgraed version?

Tags: java, android

How to get external storage path in android 4.4.2?. i am using this code `String def_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();` but i got like this `/mnt/sdcard/`

Comment: then what is wrong in this? what you are expecting?

Comment: i want to like this `/mnt/extSdCard/` ?

Comment: @Rustam can u reply me